# Using strncpy() to copy const char *

Tags: c, strncpy

I'm very new to C, I'm getting stuck using the strncpy function.\

Here's an example of what I'm working with:

```
int main()
{

const char *s = "how";

struct test {
    char *name;
};

struct test *t1 = malloc(sizeof(struct test));

strncpy(t1->name, s, sizeof(*s));
t1->name[NAMESIZE] = '\0';

printf("%s\n", t1->name);

}
```

I have a const char *, I need to set the "name" value of test to the const char. I'm having a really tough time figuring this out. Is this even the correct approach?

Thank you very much!

Comment: @KerrekSB: Very well said :D

Answer (score 5):

Well, you allocate the structure, but not the string *inside* the structure. You need to do that before you copy to it. Even when you do, you will probably overwrite unallocated memory when you attempt to set the string terminator.

And, due to a hight intake ow wine, I just noticed you actually only copy one character, but it's still *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thank you. I allocated t1->name = malloc(sizeof(s)) and then used strncpy. It works now, however it says that strncpy is a function on char but I'm using the sizeof char *.

Comment: @isal `sizeof(char*)` is 4 or 8 bytes depending on if you're on a 32 or 64 bit platform. `sizeof(*s)` is 1, as it's the same as `sizeof(char)` which is specified in the C specification to be equal to one. You should probably use `strlen(s) + 1`.

Comment: Your wine seems to have got you more rep than my whisky. Is this the real lesson here? :-S

Comment: This answer confused me a little, so I'm clarifying for other readers. `malloc(sizeof(struct test))` allocates the structure, including the char* inside it, but it does not allocate the memory to where the char* will point. When you want to use the string itself (as opposed to the pointer to it), you need to alloc new memory for it.

Comment: And I know this question is old, but how does `strncpy(t1->name, s, sizeof(*s));` only copy one character?

Comment: @LastStar007 `s` is a pointer to `char`, dereferencing `s` (which is what `*s` does) gives you a single `char`, and the size of a single `char` is always `1`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So how would you get the size of the whole string? `strlen(s)*sizeof(char)`?

Comment: @LastStar007 Only `strlen` is enough, it gives you the number of characters in the string. `sizeof(har)` is defined in the C specification to return `1` *always*.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take this one step at a time:

```
struct test *t1 = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
```

this allocates space for a `struct test`; enough space for the pointer `name`, but not any memory for the pointer to point *to*.  At a minimum, you'll want to do the following:

```
t1->name = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
```

Having done that, you can proceed to copy the string.  However, you already computed the length of the string once to allocate the memory; there's no sense in doing it again implicitly by calling `strncpy`.  Instead, do the following:

```
const size_t len = strlen(s) + 1;  // +1 accounts for terminating NUL
t1->name = malloc(len);
memcpy(t1->name, s, len);
```

In general, try to use this basic pattern; compute the length of strings *once* when they come into your code, but then use explicit-sized memory buffers and the `mem*` operations instead of implicit-length strings with `str*` operations.  It is at least as safe (and often safer) and more efficient if done properly.

You might use `strncpy` if `t1->name` was a fixed-size array instead (though many people prefer to use `strlcpy`).  That would look like the following:

```
struct test { char name[MAXSIZE]; };
struct test *t1 = malloc(sizeof *t1);
strncpy(t1->name, s, MAXSIZE - 1);
t1->name[MAXSIZE-1] = 0; // force NUL-termination
```

Note that the `size` argument to `strncpy` should always be the size of the *destination*, not the source, to avoid writing outside the bounds of the destination buffer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation, its much clearer now.

Comment: Might one call the `MAXSIZE - 1` in the `strncpy` "optimizing beyond all reason"? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Without any attempt at completeness or educational direction, here's a version of your code that should work. You can play "spot the difference" and search for an explanation for each one separately on this site.

```
int main()
{ 
    const char s[] = "how";                 // s is an array, const char[4]

    struct test{ char name[NAMESIZE]; };    // test::name is an array

    struct test * t1 = malloc(sizeof *t1);  // DRY

    strncpy(t1->name, s, NAMESIZE);         // size of the destination
    t1->name[NAMESIZE - 1] = '\0';          // because strncpy is evil

    printf("%s\n", t1->name);

    free(t1);                               // clean up
}
```

Comment: I'm not at the liberty of changing the struct definition. But I realize my mistake where I was doing malloc(sizeof struct test) and not sizeof *t1. Thank you

Comment: @isal: Then just don't forget to allocate the memory for the string as well and use [`strlen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) to calculate the size of such strings.

Comment: @isal: If you must handle `test::name` dynamically, see Stephen's answer, but don't forget to clean that up separately.

Answer (score 1):

strncpy() is **always wrong**

- if the result is too long, the target string will not be nul-terminated
- if the target is too long (the third argument) , the trailing end will be completely padded with NULs. This will waste a lot of cycles if you have large buffers and short strings.

Instead, you cound use memcpy() or strcpy, (or in your case even strdup() )

```
int main()
{
const char *s = "how";

struct test {
    char *name;
    };
struct test *t1
size_t len;

t1 = malloc(sizeof *t1);

#if USE_STRDUP

  t1->name = strdup(s);

#else

  len = strlen(s);
  t1->name = malloc (1+len);
  memcpy(t1->name, s, len);
  t1->name[len] = '\0';

#endif    

printf("%s\n", t1->name);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should that be qualified: "strncpy is always wrong *for dynamically allocated destinations*"?

Comment: No. It is always wrong. Since you manually have to repair the corner case, you could just as well use memcpy in the first place.

Comment: Hmm. Suppose you're always copying *into* a small buffer. To use `memcpy` you'd have to first get the length of the entire (possible large) string. With `strncpy` you might pay a few extra unneeded zeros, but never more than the (short) destination length.

Comment: FWIW `snprintf(dest, dest_size, "%s", src);` is a standard and does-what-you-expect replacement for `strncpy`.